# Which aluminium extrusion for LED strips has better cooling?

Tags: led-strip, thermal, cooling

I have a choice of two aluminium extrusions for LED strips. They have identical dimensions, except the one on the left has "wings" on both sides.

[image]

They will be installed in free air, suspended 10-20cm away from the ceiling for good convection cooling, LEDs pointing down (ie, upside down from the illustration).

Question: which one will have better cooling? Will the extra surface area of the "wings" help ? Or will they push the airflow away from the sides and back, making it less efficient?

Comment: I think you're overthinking this for such a tony difference.

Comment: @DKNguyen It's more of a curiosity question ;)

Comment: Visula aspect is probably far more important : I'd go with the narrower one for that alone.

Comment: You're most likely not going to see any difference between the two. This is probably more for mounting options than anything. But if one of them were to be better I'd saw its the ones with the "wings".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no fan, natural convection will dominate and the airflow will be driven by the hot surface temperature, starting at the surface. Therefore, especially in case of up-side-down there will be no air flow blocking. The surface looks like being increased be about 10%, so it is a good assumption that also the surface temperature will be reduced by roughly this amount. Radiation will increase the effect slightly if surface temperature is well above room temperature.

In case of dominating natural convection small surface changes can have a measurable impact of cooling performance. With forced convection (fan) this is usually not so much the case.